# OSGi: How to get Classloader of other bundle

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, eclipse-virgo

I have a Virgo-Tomcat-Server running. There is an EnumMap, whose key is

```
bundle.a.MyEnum
```

Context from this map is received via

```
bundle.b
```

and Spring expression language using a SpelExpressionParser, a sample expression would be "get(T(bundle.a.MyEnum).SAMPLEKEY)". The Parser (respectively its TypeLocator) needs access to the ClassLoader of bundle.a.

So I did:

```
TypeLocator typeLocator = new StandardTypeLocator(getBundleAClassLoader());
StandardEvaluationContext evaluationContext  = new StandardEvaluationContext();
evaluationContext.setTypeLocator(typeLocator);
spelExpressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
spelExpressionParser.parseExpression(expression)).getValue(evaluationContext, context);
```

The question is, what is the proper way to get the class loader of bundle.a in a class of bundle.b?
After a couple of attempts, the only working solution I found is:

```
private static ClassLoader getBundleAClassLoader() {
    MyEnum bundleARef = MyEnum.SAMPLEKEY;
    return bundleARef.getClass().getClassLoader();
}
```

**Edit: Solution**

```
getBundleAClassLoader()
```

is not necessary,

```
TypeLocator typeLocator = new StandardTypeLocator(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds too complicated. Just do an Import-Package in the Manifest of bundle.b and you can access the type in the same way as your own type.

Comment: bundle.b imports bundle.a, but without the StandardEvaluationContext, the Spring-class SpelParserExpression will use the ClassLoader of bundle.b resulting in a ClassNotFoundException

Comment: If bundle.b imports the package of MyEnum then the classloader of bundle.b will find the the class bundkle.a.MyEnum

Comment: I stand corrected, it works. Guess I had the TypeLocator not yet set correctly when I tried this.getClass().getClassLoader(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

e.g.

```
SomeClassOfBundle.class.getClassLoader()
```

or

```
bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class).getClassLoader()
```

Comment: I have tried the first suggestion and it did not work. I have also tried the second, with Bundle b = bundleContext.getBundle() which would result in bundle.b and hence in its ClassLoader. Probably I should use getBundles() instead and getting the right one.

Comment: What do you mean with "did not work"? A bundle-wiring error? You need to have an Import-Package in the Manifest file for the package of SomeClassOfBundle if you want to use the first approach.

Comment: I'm positive I had the first approach tested yesterday and received a ClassNotFoundException. However, I tested it again and it worked. Since Christians answer lead me to this.getClass().getClassLoader() I accepted his answer, but thank you nonetheless.